# Is there syntactic sugar for multiple conclusion rules in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Consider the following contrived example:

```
q(a) :- p(a), p(b).
q(b) :- p(a), p(b).
```

I would like to be able to write something like this as a single Prolog declaration, such as:

```
q(a), q(b) :- p(a), p(b).
```

The motivation being simply that, if one is building up a knowledge base in Prolog with lots of ``multiple conclusion'' rules like the example I gave above, it would be convenient to be able to write such rules on a single line somehow. Is something similar to this possible in Prolog?

Comment: Not directly, as far as I know, but you could do something like `q(X) :- p(a), p(b), member(X, [a,b]).`

Comment: @DanielLyons: `member(X,[a,b])` should be added as the first goal in `q(X)` otherwise `p(a)` and possibly `p(b)` will be executed for any value of `X`, and those goals may have side effects.

Comment: @gusbro good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the term-expansion mechanism (provided by some Prolog systems and Logtalk) to expand terms such as `q(a), q(b) :- p(a), p(b)` into a set of clauses. Something as:

```
term_expansion((','(H,Hs) :- Body), Clauses) :-
    convert_to_clauses(Hs, H, Body, Clauses).

convert_to_clauses(','(H,Hs), Head, Body, [(Head :- Body)| Clauses]) :-
    !,
    convert_to_clauses(Hs, H, Body, Clauses).
convert_to_clauses(Head2, Head, Body, [(Head :- Body), (Head2 :- Body)]).
```

Sample call:

```
?- expand_term((q(a),q(b):-p(a),p(b)), L).
L = [(q(a):-p(a), p(b)),  (q(b):-p(a), p(b))].
```

Look into your Prolog system documentation for details on the term-expansion mechanism if provided (it's not a standard mechanism). If you need/want a portable solution, Logtalk's term-expansion mechanism works the same in all (12) supported Prolog systems.